# Analysing entire dataframes instead of separate subsets in r

Tags: r, subset

I have code that analyses Gforces in movement, that returns to me a plot of GForces over time. The script works for subsets of the data (categorized by ID) and I don't have a clue how to make it compatible for analyzing the entire dataframe at once, returning to me the results in a faceted graph (with ggplot for instance). Does anyone know how to do this or am i doomed to analyse my data by one ID at a time?

The code is:

```
#Subset by ID
number1 <-subset(positions,subset=(ID==1))
head(number1)

A <- numeric()
Al <- numeric()
Radius <- numeric()
GForce <- numeric()
D12 <- numeric()
D13 <- numeric()
D23 <- numeric()
Proportion <- numeric()
Proportion_sel <- numeric()

nr<-length(number1$Timestamp)
for(i in 3:nr){

  D12[i] <- sqrt((positions$X[i-2]-positions$X[i-1])^2 + (positions$Y[i-2]-positions$Y[i-1])^2)
  D23[i] <- sqrt((positions$X[i-1]-positions$X[i])^2 + (positions$Y[i-1]-positions$Y[i])^2)
  D13[i] <- sqrt((positions$X[i-2]-positions$X[i])^2 + (positions$Y[i-2]-positions$Y[i])^2)

  if (D13[i]>0) {
    if ((((D12[i]^2+D13[i]^2-D23[i]^2)^2)/(4*(D13[i]^2))) > D12[i]^2) {
      A[i] <- 0
      Radius[i] <- 0
      GForce[i] <- 0
    } 
    else {
       A[i] <- sqrt(D12[i]^2-(((D12[i]^2+D13[i]^2-D23[i]^2)^2)/(4*(D13[i]^2))))
      Radius[i] <- ((0.5*D13[i])^2+(A[i])^2)/(2*A[i])
      GForce[i] <- ((D12[i]+D23[i])/2)^2/Radius[i]
    }
  }
  else {
    A[i] <- 0
Radius[i] <- 0
    GForce[i] <- 0
  } 

}

# GForce plot over Time
plot(number1$Timestamp,GForce)
```

This returns to me:
- a plot of Gforces over time

The problem seems to arise with finding a way to return the GForce per ID and return them as an additional column to the original dataframe. When this would be possible, it would also be easy to plot per ID using ggplot but I don't know how to accomplish this..

Data (simplified):

```
    dput(positions)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), Timestamp = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L
), X = c(-34.126, -34.087, -34.047, -34.01, -33.983, -33.973, 
-33.985, -34.019, -34.07, -34.13, -34.188, -34.237, -34.273, 
-34.295, -34.305, -34.307, -34.305, -34.301, -34.299, -34.297, 
-34.296, -34.29, -34.272, -34.235, -34.178, -34.107, -34.034, 
-33.967, -33.91, -33.865, -33.832, -33.81, -33.799, -33.8, -33.814, 
-33.841, -33.878, -33.923, -33.975, -34.033, -34.098, -34.17, 
-34.243, -34.311, -34.366, -33.691, -33.646, -33.598, -33.547, 
-33.497, -33.452, -33.414, -33.383, -33.357, -33.331, -33.302, 
-33.268, -33.234, -33.203, -33.179, -33.163, -33.154, -33.145, 
-33.132, -33.111, -33.081, -33.041, -32.993, -32.937, -32.873, 
-32.807, -32.74, -32.676, -32.611, -32.543, -32.468, -32.384, 
-32.293, -32.199, -32.109, -32.029, -31.959, -31.899, -31.846, 
-31.796, -31.749, -31.704, -31.659, -31.612, -31.561), Y = c(3.393, 
3.396, 3.398, 3.402, 3.408, 3.419, 3.434, 3.452, 3.471, 3.489, 
3.506, 3.518, 3.525, 3.526, 3.523, 3.518, 3.513, 3.511, 3.511, 
3.513, 3.516, 3.517, 3.51, 3.494, 3.467, 3.434, 3.402, 3.376, 
3.358, 3.348, 3.343, 3.343, 3.346, 3.351, 3.36, 3.373, 3.39, 
3.408, 3.43, 3.453, 3.479, 3.506, 3.532, 3.555, 3.57, 6.684, 
6.757, 6.823, 6.887, 6.953, 7.024, 7.099, 7.174, 7.245, 7.307, 
7.363, 7.414, 7.466, 7.52, 7.579, 7.643, 7.71, 7.781, 7.853, 
7.923, 7.988, 8.047, 8.098, 8.139, 8.173, 8.202, 8.228, 8.251, 
8.27, 8.285, 8.298, 8.314, 8.337, 8.372, 8.423, 8.487, 8.558, 
8.628, 8.688, 8.735, 8.768, 8.792, 8.814, 8.843, 8.881)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Timestamp", "X", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, 90L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: it's nice that you've provided data. But it would be better if you explain what your script (or your task is) is supposed to do instead of giving a huge code with no comments and say: it "works" only on a subset of my data and what's the alternative..

Comment: Well when you run it with the data provided is shows what it does so I reckoned it didn't require any further explanation. But what I want it to do is calculate the Gforces from my data, and then subsequently plot that against the prevalence of these calculated Gforces in the data. The problem is that I can only run it for ID=1 or ID=2, whereas I want it to run over my entire dataframe and return me the output of both ID 1 & 2.

Comment: If one has to "fix" your code, then one has to understand it. What you're suggesting is that I run your code and "figure it out".

Comment: Excuse me then, I thought it was clear enough to show how I wrote the code so far, and then explain the problem subsequently. To further specify my problem, I have now added a remark about not being able to write the outcome of the first part of the code to a dataframe, as far as my knowledge goes (as an r novice) that would be one step in the right direction to be able to run this code for the whole dataframe. If you have any questions concerning my question, then please feel free to ask or give constructing comments instead of only pointing out what you dislike..

Comment: If you construed my first comment as being not-constructive, then I'm sorry I can't be more polite :). You're talking about the problem at hand. In case someone has the time to sift thro' your code, you'll get an answer. For me, I'd like to know what's your code doing. Maybe you can take a small data and for that show us your output and tell "how" you got that output (ex: take column1 multiply by column2 max and store in column 3.. something like that). Otherwise, the code has to be more clearer, which I am afraid it isn't to me (again, not not-constructive, but the fact).

Comment: I was trying to simplify my question and give an example of the output while agstudy provided the answer that I needed, thanks anyway

Comment: Glad. If you want the question to remain open, I suggest you edit your post. Else it's most likely going to be voted to close.

Comment: @Joeri really here people want to help you(specially Arun you can see his previous answers). Even me I vote to close this question because I found is is specialized. Explaining the problem is half a way the solution.

Comment: Sorry sorry guys, maybe its better to close it because it is indeed to specialized, at first I attempted to ask a question with another, simpler function to make the question more generalized, but then I was afraid that the solution might lay in my function and not in lapplying the entire functions as it seems to be.. In other words, i really didn't know what to do:) Sincerely thanks for both of your help and I'll vote to close it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I join @Arun, You need to explain what are you doing.  The code is not really helpful, specially if is not well written and have some errors.

That's said , if I look in you code , you do a procees by ID. One idea is to put your code in a function and call it for each ID using `lapply`.

You create 3 plots by ID, So you can create a matrix layout , where you plot the 3 plots in each row.

```
ids <- unique(positions$ID)
layout(matrix(1:(length(ids)*3),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))
```

Then you call your process for each ID, for example:

```
lapply(ids,function(myID){
  number1 <-subset(positions,subset=(ID==myID))
  .....

  # GForce calculation
  plot(number1$Timestamp,GForce)    ## I change one line 

   ...
  sum(GForce[3:max])
})
```

[image]